# how to create the watermark table in databricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks, watermark

I would like to have a watermark table created in databricks with one column (version) and its value 1. This will be starting point. eveytime the python script will finish running I want to update the value by 1.

Goal is to use this value later before the python code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, create a watermark table in Databricks with column named "version" and set its value to 1.

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE watermarktable (
  version INT
);
INSERT INTO watermarktable VALUES (1);
```

To update the value of the "version" column by 1 after each run of Python script, you can add the following code at the end of python script.

```py
spark.sql("UPDATE watermarktable SET version = version + 1;")
```

This will update the value of the "version" column by 1 every time you run the python script.